# Retrieving data from an API

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-code

The first part of the program is to retrieve the employee user ID (or signature) from an API URL once the name has been entered. (Which I have done)

The second part, the user will enter a specific "to" and "from" date.

Using the signature obtained from the first part and the dates that the user enters, the program should pass this information to an API address and obtain information accordingly.

My question is that I am not sure how to pass the obtained signature to the new API address + the "to" and "from" date.

The first part of the program to retrieve the signature (works perfectly):

```
namespace TimeSheets_Try_11.Controllers
{
    class WebAPI
    {

        public string Getsignature(string name)
        {

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            var cookies = FullWebBrowserCookie.GetCookieInternal(new Uri(StaticStrings.UrlIora), false);
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            wc.Headers.Add("Cookie:" + cookies);
            wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            wc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            string uri = "";

            uri = StaticStrings.UrlIora + name;

            var response = wc.DownloadString(uri);

            var status = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<Employeename>>(response);

            string signame = status.Select(js => js.signature).First();
            return signame;
        }
```

The second part that I have written so far:

```
public string[] GetTime(double fromDate, double toDate, string username)
        {

            ServicePointManager.SecurityProtocol = SecurityProtocolType.Tls12;

            var cookies = FullWebBrowserCookie.GetCookieInternal(new Uri(StaticStrings.UrlNcert), false);
            WebClient wc = new WebClient();
            wc.Encoding = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8;
            wc.Headers.Add("Cookie:" + cookies);
            wc.Headers.Add("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
            wc.UseDefaultCredentials = true;
            string url = "";

            url = StaticStrings.UrlNcert + username + "&fromDate=" + fromDate + "&toDate=" + toDate;
            var respons = wc.DownloadString(url);
            OracleHour ndata = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OracleHour>(respons);
            var Get_Odnum = ndata.orderNumber;
            var Dt_Work = ndata.dateOfWork;
            var hrType = ndata.hourType;
            var hr = ndata.hours;
            var des = ndata.description;
            var surname = ndata.surveyor;

            string[] myncertdata = { Get_Odnum, Dt_Work.ToString(), hrType, hr.ToString(), des, surname };
            
            return myncertdata;
            

        }
    }
}
```

The API strings:

```
namespace TimeSheets_Try_11.Controllers
{
    class StaticStrings
    {
        public static string UrlIora = "https://iora.dnvgl.com/api/dictionary/employee/";
        public static string UrlNcert = "https://cmcservices.dnvgl.com/Finance/api/oracleReportingCost?user=VERIT" + @"\";
    }
}
```

For example if we are using the name "Jane Dow" from the date 9/22/20 - 9/29/20, the api strings will be

```
 UrlIora = "https://iora.dnvgl.com/api/dictionary/employee/Jane
UrlNcert = "https://cmcservices.dnvgl.com/Finance/api/oracleReportingCost?user=VERIT\JDOW&fromDate=2020-09-22&toDate=2020-09-29"
```

Comment: Unrelated but for your consideration: _"Remarks - Important - We don't recommend that you use the WebClient class for new development. Instead, use the System.Net.Http.HttpClient class."_ - [Docs WebClient Class](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webclient?view=netcore-3.1#remarks)

Comment: _"My question is that I am not sure how to pass the obtained signature to the new API address + the "to" and "from" date."_ - What do the docs of that API say?

Comment: _"The second part that I have written so far (the signature is not included)"_ -- why is the signature not included? Isn't that the part you need help with? **What have you tried?** The example URLs you show suggest that the "signature" aka "user ID" is provided in the usual way, as a parameter for the request. I.e. `?user=....`. Did you try including that in your string the way you include the `toDate` and `fromDate` parameters?

Comment: Looks at following : UrlNcert = "https://cmcservices.dnvgl.com/Finance/api/oracleReportingCost?user=VERIT\JDOW&fromDate=2020-09-22&toDate=2020-09-29"  You are doing a query of the URL.  Everything following the question mark are properties of the query.  Each property is separated by an Ampersand. So you are passing the user, fromDate, and toDate.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Trivial way - change UrlNcert to url without query at first:

```
class StaticStrings
{
    public static string UrlIora = "https://iora.dnvgl.com/api/dictionary/employee/";
    public static string UrlNcert = "https://cmcservices.dnvgl.com/Finance/api/oracleReportingCost";
}
```

Then in your api call get values for `username`, `fromDate` and `toDate` and use [string interpolation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/tokens/interpolated).

```
var url = $"{StaticStrings.UrlNcert}?user={username}&fromDate={fromDate:yyyy-MM-dd}&toDate={toDate:yyyy-MM-dd}";
```

If you want more complex way, check [UriBuilder](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uribuilder?view=netcore-3.1)